# How to make sub menu in Material's Popover Component

Tags: css, reactjs, css-position, material-ui, popover

I'd like to create submenu with items (utilizing Popover and MenuItem components). Can't figure out how to position the submenu so that it will be placed on the left from its parent item.

I tried to make parent  `position: relative` however wrapper prevents the submenu from displaying outside of the Popover flow.

```
<Popover
  id="simple-popper"
  open={open}
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  onClose={this.handleClose}
  anchorOrigin={{
    vertical: "bottom",
    horizontal: "center"
  }}
  transformOrigin={{
    vertical: "top",
    horizontal: "center"
  }}
>
  <MenuItem>
    Link 1
    <Paper
      style={{
        position: "absolute"
      }}
    >
      <MenuItem>SubLink 1</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>SubLink 2</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>SubLink 3</MenuItem>
    </Paper>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>Link 2</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>Link 3</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>Link 4</MenuItem>
</Popover>;
```

I'd like to implement classical two-level material design menu

Comment: I recommend looking at the cascading menu example here:  https://github.com/jcoreio/material-ui-popup-state/tree/master/demo/examples

Comment: Thanks. This is one is the ticket. Totally fits my needs.

Comment: Great! We are planning to add support for cascading menus directly into Material-UI (see discussion [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9893)), but it will probably be a few months before that is available.